# I have the Samyang FE 14mm lens which has a nondetachable lens hood - is it possible to still use a ring adaptor on this so that I can use a filter?

Tags: lens, filters, digital

And how would I know which size adaptor I need? There are no markings on my lens. I'm looking into buying a square filter holder to try help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Back in 2014 [Samyang introduced the SFH-14 filter holder](https://www.dpreview.com/articles/2328058603/samyang-announces-14mm-f2-8-lens-filter-holder) specifically made for their 14mm lenses. Cokin made three special filters that fit the holder, which uses an odd size larger than even "standard" 150mm filters: 161 x 139 x 3 mm.

[image]

The filters were:

- ND8 (three stop) neutral density
- ND4 (two stop) neutral density
- Half Blue (two stop) blue graduated neutral density

Due to the limited availability of suitable filters, it seems to have never really caught on. Four years later in 2018 a few of the holders can still be [found for sale](https://www.wexphotovideo.com/samyang-sfh-14-filter-holder-for-14mm-lens-1594101/), but good luck finding the 161mm filters to fit it! They're sometimes marketed as 'Samyang 160 filters'.

[image]

A number of third party holders made to fit the 14mm Samyang lenses for 150mm filters are available from makers such as Nisi, Haida, and Lee (three piece ring system + Lee 150mm holder). The slightly smaller 150mm filters require the holder to be closer to the lens than the 161mm filters that fit the Samyang holder. One must be careful to avoid scratching the filters with the front of the built-in lens hood on the lens. The advantage of using a 150mm holder is that there are many more options in terms of what kind of filters are available in that size.

Comment: Hi there. Thank you very much for this information - it's been very helpful. Quick question as I'm super new to filters and holders and whatnot: could you briefly explain what the millimetres mean please? Would I HAVE to have a 161mm or 150mm filter holder/filters? And if I were to purchase one, could I still use it on my smaller lens, providing I have a suitably-sized adaptor ring? Also, does it matter whether the holder is advertised as being for a auto or manual lens at all? I have an autofocus. Thank you again for all of the help.

Comment: @Man - filters are made either circular (and come in many diff sizes to thread onto the front of the lens, or square. I personally use a 100mm kit and love it. Michael's answer indicates to me that your best option is to choose a 150mmX150mm filter system, that way you can have a holder for your Samyang but also be able to use the filters with other lenses as well. If you have more q's about filter systems, ask as a new question!

Comment: @Corey awesome - thank you very much, and will do :)

Comment: Most, if not all, of those other questions have already been asked/answered here.

Answer (score 4):

You will probably have to go with something [like this](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1332364-REG/nisi_nip_fh150_sy14_nisi_150mm_filter_holder.html):

[image]

Lenses with no front threads *might* have a filter slot nearer the rear of the lens, but the Samyang you've got is not among those.

So, the semi-janky >_< filter above is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You already have many choices of makers to get the filter holder for the new ultra-wide lenses and the correct filter size, if you like the Lee filters, they have an online tool to choose the right components for your lenses and camera make: [Lee Sytem Match](http://www.leefilters.com/index.php/camera/system-match).